# Eliminating Null Values in Starting Date

Tags: sql

Good day I am trying to get items for when the unit rate was entered , which is the starting date of the unit rate, however I am getting Nulls in my starting date I am using a DATEDIFF in my script

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.[Entry No_] ,
            a.[Starting Date],
            b.[Posting Date], 
            b.[Item No_],  
            b.[Invoiced Quantity],  
            a.[Litre Conversion Factor], 
            a.[Unit Rate] , 
            b.[Location Code],  
            a.[Excise Location], 
            a.[Excise Type Code], 
            a.[Unit Of Measure Code]
FROM [Spier Live$Value Entry] b 
LEFT JOIN [Transfer Excise Tbl] a 
    ON  a.[No_] = b.[Item No_]
    AND b.[Location Code] = a.[Location Code]
    AND DateDiff(d,b.[Posting Date],a.[Starting Date]) <= 365
    AND DateDiff(d,b.[Posting Date],a.[Starting Date]) > 0
WHERE b.[Posting Date] > '2013-02-26'
  AND b.[Gen_ Bus_ Posting Group] IN ('LOCA', 'EXSA')
  AND b.[Invoiced Quantity] <> 0
  AND b.[Item No_] = 'F00335'
```

Comment: When you use `LEFT JOIN`, conditions in all but the first table should be in the `ON` clause.

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result.)

Comment: Tag the dbms used, DateDiff is a product specific function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , I don't understand what you saying

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.[Entry No_] ,
            a.[Starting Date],
            b.[Posting Date], 
            b.[Item No_],  
            b.[Invoiced Quantity],  
            a.[Litre Conversion Factor], 
            a.[Unit Rate] , 
            b.[Location Code],  
            a.[Excise Location], 
            a.[Excise Type Code], 
            a.[Unit Of Measure Code]
FROM [Spier Live$Value Entry] b 
LEFT JOIN [Transfer Excise Tbl] a 
    ON  a.[No_] = b.[Item No_]
    AND b.[Location Code] = a.[Location Code]
    AND DateDiff(d,b.[Posting Date],a.[Starting Date]) <= 365
    AND DateDiff(d,b.[Posting Date],a.[Starting Date]) > 0
WHERE b.[Posting Date] > '2013-02-26'
  AND b.[Gen_ Bus_ Posting Group] IN ('LOCA', 'EXSA')
  AND b.[Invoiced Quantity] <> 0
  AND b.[Item No_] = 'F00335' AND a.[No_] IS NOT NULL AND a.[Starting Date] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Vignesh but I am missing a 100 rows with this script I need to get 461 and your script gives me 379

Comment: Check your ramaining records whether its valid or not

Comment: my remaining records is valid

Comment: Never.. Sure remaining records `No_` or `Starting Date` must be `NULL`